# Error updating table in codeigniter when there is single quote

Tags: php, codeigniter

please help me get through with this.
Everytime I update data from database there is '\' added before the single quote.
For example I have an input that has a value=`I'm ok` after updating there is `'\'` will be added.

Sample code from my **Model**

```
    function update_questionnaire() {
          $Cid1 = $this->input->post('Cid1');
          $Cid2 = $this->input->post('Cid2');
          $Cdata = array(
            array(
                'choices_id' => $Cid1,
                'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                'choices' => $choice1
            ),
            array(
                'choices_id' => $Cid2,
                'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                'choices' => $choice2
            )
            );
            $question = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->post('question', TRUE));
            $this->db->update_batch('choices', $Cdata, 'choices_id');
      }
```

And sample code from my **Controller**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('choice1', 'Choice 1', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('choice2', 'Choice 2', 'required|trim');
```

And sample code from my **View**

```
<?php 
$i=0;
foreach ($query as $row): 
$i++;
echo '<input type="text" name="choice' . $i . '" id="choice_' . $row->choices_id . '" value="' . trim_slashes($row->choices) . '" class="form-control"/>'; 
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: If it didnt add the `\\` then all you would get in the database is characters before the first single quote, and probably a error in your insert/update

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I updated the value from`I'm ok` it will become  `I\'m ok`

Comment: replace `escape_like_str` with `$this->db->escape_st` and try

Comment: I've got an error:

`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::escape_st()

Filename: models/test_model.php

Line Number: 121

Backtrace:`

Comment: `$this->db->escape_str();` use this

Comment: I've got the same error.